# Provide all users with ability to edit their own specific attributes in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been working on a project that allows users in our domain to edit 3 Active Directory Attributes on their own Object, this has been written in Python and the only issue I have now is user permissions on these attributes.

Two of these are custom, the third is the Location(physicalOfficeDeliveryAddress).
I have looked everywhere and only found documentation on how to give permission for users in a group for these attributes but for ALL users or limited by group.

I'm looking to apply the permission under the Identity Reference: NT AUTHORITY\SELF so that users may only edit their own attributes.

In less words, I'm looking to write a script that will delegate permissions for three specific attributes to ALL users in the domain but only for themselves(NT AUTH\SELF).

I have a loop that will perform it for each user, I just have hit a brick wall in what to include in the loop..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should run your script using service account which has write access to all users. However, application logic should check if user is authorized to request the change and process accordingly.

Comment: @robdy This was the original plan with my pitch for this tool however our Security Consultant does not wish for us to use Service Accounts as these are against best security practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NT AUTHORITY\SELF` is one of Windows' [well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids), with a SID of `S-1-5-10`.

So you do it the same way you would for any other account, but grant the permissions to `S-1-5-10` instead.

If you show us the code you're working with, we might be able to help you with where to plug in that value, if you need.

Comment: I probably do not understand how SELF works properly then..
If I simply provide permissions for write/read access to a user with the SID s-1-5-10, will it then provide all users in the domain those write/read rights on their own object?

I was under the impression you had to delegate access to each individual user under the SELF user, similar to how you would provide permissions to a certain user for folder access (except the user is the folder)?

Comment: The documentation says "During an access check, the system replaces the SID with the SID of the object." So `SELF` (i.e. a SID of `S-1-5-10`) is interpreted to be the SID of the object itself.

Comment: You don't need to apply this permission to every object specifically. You can add this `SELF` permission at the domain level, or an OU level and make it inheritable to all user objects. That might be easier than writing the script you're thinking about.

Comment: Okay, it seems that would work better - is this different from Delegate Control using the ADUC Gui?

Comment: It's the same thing. The "Delegate Control" feature is just a fancy UI for changing the security settings on an object.